# PHP: Creating a "persistent" session for a webshop-like site

Tags: php, session, e-commerce, session-cookies, webshop

**Hello everyone,
This is mostly a proof-reading question, if I may put it like that.**

So, **I need to create a persistent session for a webshop/e-commerce site**. A session lasting over the specified time is not really an issue, but making it last for, say 24 hours since the last click, is important.

**Why:** To quickly check cart status, last visited pages, tax- and currency choices etc. without querying, let alone writing to the database or some other storage mechanism on each page request. The cart and browsing history are complicated enough to be stored in a session, Language, currency etc. could admittedly be cookies as well.
Most of our site is cached as html, and only a few elements like cart contents are strapped to the otherwise finished page. We have very good server response times, and I'd like to keep them that way and avoid anything too heavy especially for users who don't have anything in their cart.

I've gone through quite a few posts on StackOverflow and Google in general to get a basic idea of this. Most results were about being concerned and making sure the session would close in any case after a certain period of time. This case is the opposite.

**So, PHP has a few session setting in the ini, of which three are the most important:**

- **session.gc_maxlifetime**: Determines the time after which a garbage collection cycle will remove the file. This is not an exact time, it
  is a minimum time for the session to last *since the last change of
  the $_SESSION variable data*. Default is 1440 seconds / 24 minutes.
- **session.cookie_lifetime**: This is the lifetime for the PHPSESSID -cookie which enables PHP to fetch a corresponding session. This defaults to zero, which means the cookie is destroyed when the
  browser closes. It could thus live for one millisecond or two years
  if set to zero.

  Setting this to an integer value will give the cookie an expiration
  *from the time it is first set*. The lifetime will not be forwarded on subsequent page loads with session starts.
- **session.save_path:** Tells PHP where to save the session files. This is also the directory which will get garbage collected for
  expired sessions.

So here's an example "session header" I came up with. It should at least ensure session files are stored for at least $lt seconds from the *first* session start, and the session cookie $lt seconds from the *last* execution of this script. In the question -comment the session gets written to, which would in my thoughts cause the file time to get updated, and thus push session expiry to $lt since the *last* execution of the script.

```
<?php
/**
* Example "header" to start a session in a simple environment
*/

// Lifetime setting in seconds
$lt = 1440;

// Set maxlives to $lt
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $lt);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', $lt);

// Save sessions in a different directory than other sessions. The gc
// will run on a probability base on each session start and clean the default
// directory. If our (longer) sessions are saved in a shared session dir
// for other PHP scripts which have a shorter expiry, our files will also be
// removed.
// If we run a single site, use php.ini to set the above max lives,
// or are the only ones using sessions, we can omit this directive.
ini_set('session.save_path', '/var/www/mysite/separate-session-dir');

// Start the session AFTER setting the parameters
session_start();

// Update the cookie expiration on a page load.
// This will simply overwrite the system-set session cookie.        
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lt, '/');

// QUESTION: Would this forward the session FILE lifetime by writing to it.
$_SESSION['random-field'] = uniqid();

// Do what you really meant to do with your script.
```

**So. Here it is. Does this work as a simple way to ensure sessions live for at least $lt seconds, or have I overlooked something?**

I am currently running this on our server, without the ini_sets and save path as they are set in the php.ini instead. The cookie part seems easy enough to verify by closing the browser and returning to see if a cart is emptied or not, but the file -part is harder to verify and I'd like your input about this.

PS. Sorry about stuffing e-commerce/webshop tags, but I searched for hours for a post which would look at things from this perspective.

Comment: You'd want to change the actual `.ini` file, not use `ini_set`, because any script that doesn't have your `ini_set` commands in it could inadvertently cause the default garbage collection to fire. That said, why not just use a separate cookie and leave the session handling unchanged?

Comment: I actually did set the .ini in my real implementation as i'm running several sites. This is basically a "single script" / "include in all files -header" example. Am I correct, that a separate directory is also "required" to make sure other scripts with lower lifetimes won't delete the entries? I recall the gc in some cases (Debian?) is simply a cron, reading these settings from the php.ini and then checking overdue files in the directory.

Comment: I can't speak for Debian's specific configuration, but my understanding is that PHP's garbage collection is handled within the PHP process itself - one out of X random pageviews (depending on the `session.gc_probability` value) triggers GC as the script ends. Isolating your sessions by putting them in a different, non-standard directory should help.

Comment: @ceejayoz: You are correct, php handles it. I run CentOs, but came across a situation where gc(_probability?) was set off (to never run through php), and was ran as a separate cron each 30 minutes on some Debian installs.

How would a separate cookie solve this, provided we wouldn't save all the cart & history data in the cookies? A cookie could refer to some other temp file or database, but wouldn't that be a re-invent of session? The idea being, i dont want each and everything in the $_SESSION to be visible to the user either as it's a bunch of stuff.

Comment: It wouldn't be unusual to store one's cart as a cookie. The rest of the session could be stored in a session, as usual. Just a potential option.